# How to stop browser from loading display:none content?

Tags: css, video, load, breakpoints, display

I have multiple header videos for different screen sizes. The higher res are hidden for mobile but they still get loaded in the background. Vice versa for desktop.

Is there a way to set the browser to load only what's shown and skip the unnecessary downloads?

Comment: when you use display: none the element still get's loaded, it just don't get shown, to do that you will need to physically remove elements. you can add logic that will add the elements when needed.

Comment: So it's not possible to not download the non visible content without removing it with javascript?

Comment: can you provide me with the html tree?